# Statement in linq lambda expression

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I have a list of it, that is my SelectedValue from some ComboBox.

```vb
 Dim AppsInt = MyApps.CheckedItems.Select(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x.Value)).ToList()
```

And i have this object that is a list( of t)

```vb
 Dim myObj = New List( Of Item )
 Dim FooItem = New item ( 42 )
```

What I want is to get my list of Int into my object. With Something that would look like this in C#:

```cs
AppsInt.foreach( x => myObj .add(new Item(x) ) ) ;
```

What i have done so far is sending me a "do not produce a result" error:

```cs
AppsInt.ForEach( Function(it) myObj.Add(New Item(it)) )
```

How can i do it ? How to make this linq lambda work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda expression inside you `ForEach` expression does not returns any result (and compiler said it to you). It means that you have two ways to solve it:

1. Add return statement into your lamda expression that will return *anything*:

   ```
   AppsInt.ForEach(Function(it) 
              myObj.Add(New Item(it))
              Return 1 ' it's not matter what you will return here.
          End Function)
   ```
2. Change `Function(it)` to `Sub(it)`. `Sub` is not obliged to return any value.

Second option is more preferable.

Answer (score 2):

you should change function(it) to sub(it) . 
Or:

```
Dim myObj = AppsInt.Select( Function(it) New Item(it)).ToArray()
```

Comment: feeeper is a little more clear but you where the fastest aka the one that fixed my issue. So You have my +1 . but he has to get the solved flag.